# Почему получается слишком больная погрешность ?(Метод Рунге-Кутта)

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь вычислить оду 1-го порядка с помощью метода рунге-кутта, но выдает слишком большую погрешность. Где ошибка в коде?

```
class Program
{
    static float x0 = 0, y0 = -2;

    static int a = 0;
    static int b = 2;
    static float h = (float)0.25;

    static float Numerical_Solution(float x)
    {
        return ((float)(2 * Math.Pow(x, 2) - 2));

    }

    static float F(float x, float y)
    {

       return ((float)(3*x-0.5*x*y+Math.Pow(x,3)));

    }

    static float Eiler(int N, float h)
    {
        float x, y, y_prev = y0, error, max_error = 0;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("При N=" + N + ", шаг h= " + h);
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
        {
            x = x0 + i * h;
            if (i == 0)
            { y = y0; }
            else
            { y = y_prev + h * F(x, y_prev); }
            error = y - Numerical_Solution(x);
            Console.WriteLine(i + " x= " + x + "  y(Э)= " + y + "  y(точ)= " + Numerical_Solution(x) + "  погрешность= " + error);
            if (error > max_error)
                max_error = error;
            y_prev = y;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("максимальная ошибка = " + max_error);
        return max_error;
    }

    static float Eiler_Coche(int N, float h)
    {
        float x, yi,            // y[i]
                yi__,           // y[i-1/2]
                y_prev = y0,    // y[i-1]
                error, max_error = 0;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("При N=" + N + ", шаг h= " + h);
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
        {
            x = x0 + i * h;
        if (i == 0)
           { yi = y0; }
          else
           {
                yi__ = y_prev + h / 2 * F(x, y_prev);
                yi = y_prev + h * F(x - h / 2, yi__);
            }
            error = yi - Numerical_Solution(x);
            Console.WriteLine(i + " x= " + x + "  y(Э-К)= " + yi + "  y(точ)= " + Numerical_Solution(x) + "  погрешность= " + error);
            if (error > max_error)
                max_error = error;
            y_prev = yi;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("максимальная ошибка = " + max_error);
        return max_error;
    }
    static float RungeKuta(int N, float h) //составить
    {
        float x, yii, yi_=0 , k1=0 , k2=0 , k3 =0, k4=0 , y_prev = y0, error, max_error = 0;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("При N=" + N + ", шаг h= " + h);
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
        {
            x = x0 + i * h;
           //x=1+(i-1)*h;

            if (i == 0)
            { yii = y0; }
            else
            {


                k1 = F(x, y_prev);
                k2 = F(x + (h / 2), y_prev + (h * k1) / 2);
                k3 = F(x + (h / 2), y_prev + (h * k2) / 2);
                k4 = F(x + h, y_prev + (h * k3));
                yi_ = h/6 * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4);
                yii = y_prev + yi_;
            }

            error = yii - Numerical_Solution(x);
            Console.WriteLine(i + " x= " + x + "  y(Р)= " + yii + "  y(точ)= " + Numerical_Solution(x) + "  погрешность= " + error+"   "+yi_+"  "+y_prev);
            if (error > max_error)
                max_error = error;
            y_prev = yii;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("максимальная ошибка = " + max_error);
        return max_error;
}
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int N = (int)(((b - a) / h) + 1);
        Console.WriteLine("Метод Эйлера :");
        Eiler(N,h);
       //// Eiler(20);
       // Eiler(40);
        Console.WriteLine("\nМетод Эйлера-Коши :");
        Eiler_Coche(N,h);
       // Eiler_Coche(20);
        //Eiler_Coche(40);

        Console.WriteLine("\nМетод Рунге :");
        RungeKuta(N, h);
        // Eiler_Coche(20);
        //Eiler_Coche(40);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Что значит `слишком большая `? Это сколько?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну явно больше,чем методом Эйлера. Разве не должно быть иначе? Вроде метод Рунге-Кутта должен иметь более приближенные значения. Или я ошибаюсь?